# Jasmine fixtures not cleaned up, tests not independent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, fixtures

I'm using Jasmine to unit test some table column sorting functionality. An issue came up where I noticed that my columns were in the wrong order (Z-A instead of A-Z) after my first click. I used the browser's debugger to examine the html and confirm that the column was in fact mis-sorted. As a test of independence, I added an extra click to the end of the preceding it-block, and surprisingly this fixed the issue. Reordering my tests to avoid the other's click also worked.

This disproves [the assertion](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery#html-fixtures) that the "fixtures container is automatically cleaned-up between tests". Can anyone verify this bug or explain what I'm misunderstanding?

```
describe('gem bootstrap_sortable_rails', function() {
  var header;
  beforeEach(function() {
    setFixtures('<table class="sortable"><thead><tr><th data-sortkey="0">Name</th></tr></thead>' +
        '<tbody><tr><td data-value="Harrow Baptist Church"><a href="/organizations/1">Harrow Baptist Church</td></tr>' +
        '<tr><td data-value="Human Touch Worldwide"><a href="/organizations/1">Human Touch Worldwide</td></tr></tbody></table>');
    header = $('th');
  });
  describe('when clicking on the tableheader', function() {
    it('inserts an arrow after click', function() {
      header.click();
      expect(header.find('span')).toHaveClass('arrow');
      header.click();    // added to make the test below pass!
    });
    it('sorts A-Z then Z-A', function() {
      header.click();
      expect($('td').first()).toHaveText('Harrow Baptist Church');
      header.click();
      expect($('td').first()).toHaveText('Human Touch Worldwide')
    });
  });
});
```

ruby 1.9.3,
rails 3.2.14,
[jasmine-jquery-rails 1.5.9](https://github.com/travisjeffery/jasmine-jquery-rails/blob/73db5fd0af0cf40d4601a3d1aa86aaf32a6d528f/vendor/assets/javascripts/jasmine-jquery.js).

I just upgraded to jasmine 2.0 and jasmine-jquery-rails 2.0.2, no difference.